When selecting lines in konsole using the mouse, the paste doesn't include the carriage return to an SSH session
If I select anything from the command line that includes the end of the line, when I paste it into a konsole window or tab that is ssh'd in to a remote machine, the carriage return is not pasted. It doesn't matter whether I use the mouse to do the copy-and-paste, or use keyboard shortcuts.
If the destination tab is a local shell, then the carriage return is pasted. The result is that if it's a local tab that I paste a command into, it runs immediately, but if it's a remote tab then it just pastes the command plus a newline, but I still have to manually hit enter.

Copy a command line including the end of the line.
Paste this into a konsole tab or window (either the same, or a different local shell, or a shell that is ssh'd in to a remote system).
Expect the same behavior: the command runs immediately
If the destination tab or window is local, the command runs immediately as expected.
If the destination tab or window is logged into a remote system, the command does not run, but requires additional keyboard input to hit the enter key.


Please do not cross-post. For the record, the other copy is on Super User.

Thanks for the feedback. I deleted the other post.

@KamilMaciorowski is it acceptable to ask for feedback on ways that I can improve this question. Would screenshots help?
